# Defining a function that prints both the name and value of a variable defined locally within the calling function

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, variable-definitions, scoping, printing

To save time when debugging with Print statements, I'd like to define a function -- call it PrintVal -- that prints both the name and value of a variable defined locally within the calling function.  The function would be called with a *single* argument, which would be the name of the variable in question (expressed in the form of a string).  To provide a concrete example, if fooVar is a variable defined as local to a module within the calling function, and if the current value of fooVar is 9, then

```
PrintVal[ "fooVar" ]
```

should print

```
fooVar = 9
```

The new function would thus have the same effect as including the statement

```
Print[ "fooVar = ", fooVar ]
```

directly within the calling function itself, but without the need to type the variable name twice, to include the equal sign, and (most important from a time-saving perspective) to include some other formatting stuff that I haven't mentioned here (because it's not relevant to the part I'm struggling with).

Although there may well be an embarrassingly simple solution that I don't know enough to have thought of, after a considerable amount of experimentation, documentation-reading, and web-searching, I've been unable to find one.  With apologies in advance if I'm missing something obvious, I'd be very grateful to anyone who might provide a (detailed and concrete) solution.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is it necessary for the argument to be passed as a String?  Could you use `PrintVal[fooVar]` instead if the output were the same?

Comment: Mr. Wizard:  No need for the argument to be specified as a string.  Indeed, specifying the argument to PrintVal without having to include the quotes will save me even more time, and the solution you've provided below seems to work perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad I could help, and thanks for the Accept. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a method that is not exactly to your specification but which may serve you anyway.  It  uses a Symbol argument.  Because a Symbol is passed it is automatically modified by `Module` and does not need the guesswork of [`$ModuleNumber`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ModuleNumber.html) etc. but it does need string conversion and cleanup.

```
SetAttributes[printVal, HoldFirst];

printVal[s_Symbol] := 
  Print @ Row[{StringTrim[SymbolName@Unevaluated@s, "$" ~~ DigitCharacter ..], s}, "="]
```

An example:

```
b = "Fail!" (*this should not print!*);

Module[{b},
 b = RandomInteger[9, 3]^2;
 printVal[b];
 b
]
```

> b = {16, 4, 36}
>
> ```
> {16, 4, 36}
> ```

---

Regarding why naive attempts fail you must consider the mechanism of [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html); only visible (explicit) Symbols in the body are substituted by localized equivalents.  A String that is later converted to a Symbol is not included in this localization:

```
b = "Fail!";

Module[{b},
 b = RandomInteger[9, 3]^2;
 Print[b];
 Print[Unevaluated@b];
 Print[Symbol["b"]];
]
```

> {81, 64, 36}
>
> b$2061
>
> Fail!

Note that `Symbol["b"]` evaluates to the global `b` rather than the localized `b$2061`.

Comment: You may add `..` to `"$"` so it works well in `DynamicModule` too. One should be careful where it is called there anyway.

Comment: @Kuba I hadn't thought about `DynamicModule`.  (Thanks for reminding me.)  I don't know how this would behave there; I need to think about that.

Comment: Printing should be held till DM content is displayed. `DynamicModule[{b},
 {
  Slider[Dynamic[b, (b = #; printVal[b];) &]],
  
  printVal[b]; SymbolName[Unevaluated@b],
  Button["print b", printVal[b]]
  
  }]`

Comment: As noted above, in the quick tests I've just run, @Mr.Wizard's solution seems to work perfectly for me.  I'm also grateful to Kuba for his comment.  Many thanks to both of you!

Comment: I tried this solution on a Manipulate Control variable, and it gave unexpected results ("b\$" instead of "b"). The reason was that these variables use two "\$"s and not just one. The easy fix is to use ("\$"..) instead of just "\$" in the String pattern.

Comment: @SpencerRugaber  Belated thanks for pointing out this potential pitfall, and for your suggestion on how to avoid falling into that pit.